# Would an empty src attribute cause a request on any browser?

Tags: html, asp.net, image

I wonder if it's safe to have an html image tag like this

```
<img src width="30" height="20"/>
```

ASP.NET Image control render like this when ImageUrl is not set. I fill src attribute later on client side

I want to be sure that this is not causing any request to server on any browser. I imagine this is the case but wanted to double check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use it like this

```
<img src="" width="30" height="20"/>
```

you can still set it in client-side script

the easiest test is the code below

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<img src="" />

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

if you save this code as an html file in your local computer, then open it in chrome. press F12 . you will see DEVELOPER CONSOLE opens. click the NETWORK tab. when you reload the page, you will see it only requests the html file. but if you give a dummy source  like below

```
<img src="test.png" width="30" height="20"/>
```

when you reload the page with "test.png", you will see it makes a request for html and image. but if you leave blank the source like src="", it wont make a request for image tag

Comment: I was actually confused and it's rendering like this `src=""` but I wonder if this is totally safe in all browsers. I want to be sure that won't generate a request to server assuming current url path as image path

Comment: wait 2 mins. I will check it for you. I will create one to test and watch the network

Comment: I edited my answer. please check. if you leave it as src="", it doesnt make a request for image

Comment: @ayilmaz: I know that latest browser versions work like this as I tested myself befores asking this questions :) but I wanted to be sure that this behavior was always like this for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% positive, which I think leaving it blank would be fine, you can set the src to a transparent image, then change it.  It seems like a lot of work because leaving it blank would be the best bet.